# A Graphics`Mesh`ConvexHull[] peculiarity

Tags: computational-geometry, version-8, undocumented

I have been unable to explain the behavior of `` Graphics`Mesh`ConvexHull[] `` on the following (highly simplified) example:

```
pts = {{-1/6, -1/18}, {-4/31, 1/9}, {-1/26, -12/73},
       {1/6, 2/37}, {1/26, 12/73}, {4/31, -1/9}};

Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[];

idx = ConvexHull[pts];

idx2 = Most[First[FindCurvePath[pts]]];

GraphicsRow[{Graphics[Line[pts]], Graphics[Line[pts[[idx]]]], Graphics[Line[pts[[idx2]]]]}]
```

I get the following result on my system (version 8.0.4 on Linux, if it matters):

[image: convex hull attempts on my points]

As you can see, `ConvexHull[]` does not seem to work properly on my set of points, while `FindCurvePath[]` has no problem. However, I had wanted to use `ConvexHull[]` because it consistently orders points in an anticlockwise manner (or at the very least it seems to), while `FindCurvePath[]` sometimes orders points clockwise. I can break down and just implement the Graham scan myself, but I'd prefer to understand why the hidden convex hull routine is not behaving in the manner I expect.

Comment: Why are you bothering with `Graphics\`Mesh`?

Comment: See my comment to your answer.

Comment: Is `Graphics``Mesh` documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I can not reproduce your problem. When I carry out the following evaluations

```
Needs@"ComputationalGeometry`"

GraphicsRow@{
  Graphics[Line@pts], 
  Graphics[Line@pts[[ConvexHull[pts]]]]}
```

I get

[image]

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, I was using ``Graphics`Mesh`ConvexHull[]`` and not the implementation from the Computational Geometry package (I am aware of that, but due to a number of reasons, I prefer not to have to load a package)...

Comment: @CarlosCulo. If that's the case, then you are probably stick with the behavior you observe.